# Batch file to put files in folder (only subfolders)

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that currently puts every file in a folder with the name of the file.  However it only works for that folder I am in.  I would like to have one batch file at the top of my directory that will only execute files 2 subfolders down.  Example of directory:

```
/Parent folder **This is where I want my batch file**
  /Subfolder 1
    /Subfolder 1A/file.jpg **Level I want batch file to execute**
    /Subfolder 1B/file.mp4 **Level I want batch file to execute**
    /Subfolder 1C/file.mp3 **Level I want batch file to execute**
  /Subfolder 2
    /Subfolder 2A/file.jpg **Level I want batch file to execute**
    /Subfolder 2B/file.mp4 **Level I want batch file to execute**
    /Subfolder 2C/file.mp3 **Level I want batch file to execute**
```

This is my current batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
    md "%%~na" 2>nul
    move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

Comment: what do you want the batch file to do exactly?

Comment: I want it to put every file into a folder with the same name as the file.  The current batch file I have does this but only in the current folder.

Comment: So for e.g. you want `file.jpg` in `Subfolder 1A` to go into `Subfolder 1A/File/` ?

Comment: Correct is that possible having the batch file at the top of the directory in the parent folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FOR loop with the /D option to iterate folders, repeating for as many levels as necessary. Use PUSHD at each step so that you don't have to keep track of the full path.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  pushd "%%a"
  for /d %%b in (*) do (
    pushd "%%b"
    for %%c in (*) do (
      md "%%~nc" 2>nul
      move "%%c" "%%~nc"
    )
    popd
  )
  popd
)
```

You can use `%~dp0` to guarantee you start at the parent folder of the batch script:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("%~dp0*") do (
  pushd "%%a"
  for /d %%b in (*) do (
    pushd "%%b"
    for %%c in (*) do (
      md "%%~nc" 2>nul
      move "%%c" "%%~nc"
    )
    popd
  )
  popd
)
```

The code becomes tedious as you add more levels. You can use recursion to write more generic code that can easily be changed to work at any subfolder depth. Simply change the depth value as needed. Note how you can re-use letters within nested FOR loops.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set depth=2

:iterateFolders
setlocal
set /a depth-=1
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  pushd "%%F"
  if %depth% gtr 0 (
    call :iterateFolders
  ) else for %%F in (*) do (
    md "%%~nF" 2>nul
    move "%%F" "%%~nF"
  )
  popd
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you so much dbenham it worked and this will save a whole lot of time.